# Como resgatar os valores dos EditText criados via script?

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte código que cria 4 EditText no Layout:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.formulario);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    EditText[] pairs=new EditText[4];
    for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
    {
        pairs[l] = new EditText(this);
        pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
        pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[l].setId(l);
        pairs[l].setText((l + 1) + ": something");
        myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
    }
```

Como faço para resgatar os valores de cada campo?

Comment: Se entendi a pergunta será assim `pairs[0].getText().toString()`

Comment: Ok @ramaral, mas isso a partir do código que postei? o `new EditText()` serve para resgatar valores também? vc pode ser mais específico?

Comment: Tendo por base o que postou não posso ser mais especifico. Nem sequer tenho a certeza se é isso o que você quer.

Comment: Agora ainda mais confuso fiquei com "o new EditText() serve para resgatar valores também?" O que quer dizer com "resgatar"?

Comment: @ramaral o código que eu postei cria 4 campos do tipo EditText. Quando digo que quero resgatar valores, estou dizendo que quero pegar o que foi  digitado em cada campo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder ter acesso ao conteúdo digitado em cada um dos *EditText* use:

```
String textoDigitado = pairs[indice].getText().toString();
```

onde `indice` é a posição do *EditText* no *array* cujo conteúdo quer obter.

Se quiser ter acesso ao *array* `pairs` em qualquer local da sua *Activity* deverá declará-lo como um campo da mesma.

```
private EditText[] pairs;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.formulario);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pairs = new EditText[4];
    for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
    {
        pairs[l] = new EditText(this);
        pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
        pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[l].setId(l);
        pairs[l].setText((l + 1) + ": something");
        myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. funcionou pra mim.